# Vino-server does not work since update to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, vnc, vino

Since I updated to Oneric Ocelot vino-server does not work on my machine any more. Although I set every thing exactly as before, it is not be started when System starts or I log in. Trying to start it manually with the command

`/usr/lib/vino/vino-server`

I get an error message like this:

```
(vino-server:20260): EggSMClient-CRITICAL **: egg_sm_client_set_mode: assertion `global_client == NULL || global_client_mode == EGG_SM_CLIENT_MODE_DISABLED' failed
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Autoprobing TCP port in (all) network interface
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Listening IPv6://[::]:5900
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Listening IPv4://0.0.0.0:5900
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Autoprobing selected port 5900
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Re-binding socket to listen for VNC connections on TCP port 5900 in (all) interface
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Listening IPv6://[::]:5900
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Listening IPv4://0.0.0.0:5900
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Clearing securityTypes
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Clearing securityTypes
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Advertising authentication type: 'No Authentication' (1)
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Re-binding socket to listen for VNC connections on TCP port 5900 in (all) interface
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Listening IPv6://[::]:5900
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Listening IPv4://0.0.0.0:5900
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Clearing securityTypes
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Clearing authTypes
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Advertising authentication type: 'VNC Authentication' (2)
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Clearing securityTypes
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Clearing authTypes
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Advertising authentication type: 'VNC Authentication' (2)
09/11/2011 03:58:46 Advertising security type: 'VNC Authentication' (2)
*** glibc detected *** /usr/lib/vino/vino-server: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000001c3ff10 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x78a96)[0x7f5db2a7ea96]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7a5f8)[0x7f5db2a805f8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x6d)[0x7f5db2a8277d]
/usr/lib/libminiupnpc.so.5(soapPostSubmit+0xf2)[0x7f5db3f3c202]
/usr/lib/libminiupnpc.so.5(+0x35eb)[0x7f5db3f3c5eb]
/usr/lib/libminiupnpc.so.5(UPNP_GetStatusInfo+0x82)[0x7f5db3f3dc32]
/usr/lib/libminiupnpc.so.5(UPNPIGD_IsConnected+0x39)[0x7f5db3f3d039]
/usr/lib/libminiupnpc.so.5(UPNP_GetValidIGD+0x182)[0x7f5db3f3d1f2]
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server[0x415e97]
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server[0x4163b8]
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server[0x40f1a4]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0(+0xb7afa)[0x7f5db56d2afa]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0(g_simple_async_result_complete+0x87)[0x7f5db5682c17]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0(+0xafa3a)[0x7f5db56caa3a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0(g_simple_async_result_complete+0x87)[0x7f5db5682c17]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0(+0x67d29)[0x7f5db5682d29]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x1dd)[0x7f5db4629a5d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x45258)[0x7f5db462a258]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_loop_run+0x162)[0x7f5db462a792]
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server[0x40ba1b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x7f5db2a2730d]
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server[0x40bafd]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00443000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1978132                            /usr/lib/vino/vino-server
00642000-00643000 r--p 00042000 08:01 1978132                            /usr/lib/vino/vino-server
00643000-00645000 rw-p 00043000 08:01 1978132                            /usr/lib/vino/vino-server
00645000-00652000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
01a87000-01c54000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f5da4000000-7f5da4021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5da4021000-7f5da8000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5da95cd000-7f5da95e2000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 396975                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f5da95e2000-7f5da97e1000 ---p 00015000 08:01 396975                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f5da97e1000-7f5da97e2000 r--p 00014000 08:01 396975                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f5da97e2000-7f5da97e3000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 396975                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f5da97e3000-7f5da97e4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5da97e4000-7f5da9fe4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5da9fe4000-7f5da9fe5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5da9fe5000-7f5daa7e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5daa7e5000-7f5daa7e6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5daa7e6000-7f5daafe6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5daafe6000-7f5daafea000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2754313                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
7f5daafea000-7f5dab1ea000 ---p 00004000 08:01 2754313                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
7f5dab1ea000-7f5dab1eb000 r--p 00004000 08:01 2754313                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
7f5dab1eb000-7f5dab1ec000 rw-p 00005000 08:01 2754313                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/2.10.0/loaders/libpixbufloader-png.so
7f5dab1ec000-7f5dab1fa000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2230326                    /usr/lib/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/theming-engines/libunico.so
7f5dab1fa000-7f5dab3f9000 ---p 0000e000 08:01 2230326                    /usr/lib/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/theming-engines/libunico.so
7f5dab3f9000-7f5dab3fa000 r--p 0000d000 08:01 2230326                    /usr/lib/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/theming-engines/libunico.so
7f5dab3fa000-7f5dab3fb000 rw-p 0000e000 08:01 2230326                    /usr/lib/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/theming-engines/libunico.so
7f5dab3fb000-7f5dab408000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 396987                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.12.0
7f5dab408000-7f5dab607000 ---p 0000d000 08:01 396987                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.12.0
7f5dab607000-7f5dab608000 r--p 0000c000 08:01 396987                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.12.0
7f5dab608000-7f5dab609000 rw-p 0000d000 08:01 396987                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.12.0
7f5dab609000-7f5dab632000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2100143                    /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
7f5dab632000-7f5dab832000 ---p 00029000 08:01 2100143                    /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
7f5dab832000-7f5dab833000 r--p 00029000 08:01 2100143                    /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
7f5dab833000-7f5dab834000 rw-p 0002a000 08:01 2100143                    /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
7f5dab834000-7f5dab835000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f5dab835000-7f5dab83c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2106560                    /usr/lib/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
7f5dab83c000-7f5daba3c000 ---p 00007000 08:01 2106560                    /usr/lib/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
7f5daba3c000-7f5daba3d000 r--p 00007000 08:01 2106560                    /usr/lib/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
7f5daba3d000-7f5daba3e000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 2106560                    /usr/lib/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
7f5daba3e000-7f5daba54000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1841289                    /usr/lib/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7f5daba54000-7f5dabc53000 ---p 00016000 08:01 1841289                    /usr/lib/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7f5dabc53000-7f5dabc54000 r--p 00015000 08:01 1841289                    /usr/lib/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7f5dabc54000-7f5dabc55000 rw-p 00016000 08:01 1841289                    /usr/lib/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so
7f5dabc55000-7f5dabc68000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2100142                    /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7f5dabc68000-7f5dabe67000 ---p 00013000 08:01 2100142                    /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7f5dabe67000-7f5dabe68000 r--p 00012000 08:01 2100142                    /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7f5dabe68000-7f5dabe69000 rw-p 00013000 08:01 2100142                    /usr/lib/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
7f5dabe69000-7f5dabe6f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1966386                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.7.1
7f5dabe6f000-7f5dac06e000 ---p 00006000 08:01 1966386                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.7.1
7f5dac06e000-7f5dac06f000 r--p 00005000 08:01 1966386                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.7.1
7f5dac06f000-7f5dac070000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 1966386                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.7.1Abgebrochen
```

What am I suppose to do? Thanks for helping!

Comment: This is the same issue as: http://askubuntu.com/questions/83824/how-can-i-start-a-vnc-server-before-login

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a bug. See below:

1. [Launchpad bug #869948](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/869948) (duplicate of 2nd, but matching error message)
2. [Launchpad bug #841384](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vino/+bug/841384)

Possible workarounds are detailed in the forum thread (mentioned in the second bug report):

- [Upgrading to 11.10 breaks VNC (vino)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861707)

One possible solution is to install and *use GNOME Classic*, the other seems to be to *use a different VNC server* eg. `x11vnc`.

Comment: Is there any body out there knowing a way out of this mass? Dear Ubuntu team please, for the love of God, test your system before releasing it!

Comment: Updated answer with the reference to the related Ubuntu Forums topic.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest fix is to reinstall vino:

```
sudo apt-get remove vino
sudo apt-get install vino
```

Saw another post where this worked for the majority of users.
You've probably done this already but don't forget to Pref > and Set Desktop Sharing.

I personally think Vino is easier to use than x11vnc, but you could try that too, as suggested.