# Vino VNC Server unable to start on startup

Tags: server, gnome, ssh, remote-desktop, vnc

So I am trying to get the Vino VNC Server to startup on boot, meaning I don't have to login to have the VNC Server start. I am on Ubuntu GNOME 15.04, and I have already added

```
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server
```

to 'Startup Applications'. However, the VNC Server still won't start as soon as I boot up. I have to login in order for the VNC Server to start. What should I do? Do I need to create a systemd unit file? If so, how do I do it?

**Edit**: This question is different from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83824/how-can-i-start-a-vnc-server-before-log-on) becuase I need Vino Server to work, while that guide suggests x11vncserver.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I start a VNC server before log on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/83824/how-can-i-start-a-vnc-server-before-log-on)

Comment: @markkirby I've edited the post on why my post is different, also, the suggestion of automatic login is not something that I can risk.

Comment: I too would like to know how to get Vino to start on boot.

Comment: Have a look at [these answers here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918137/start-synergy-or-any-application-before-logging-in-ubuntu-16-04-2-lts)

Comment: @MarkKirby - The OP you linked is not about vino, but "a VNC server", and actually most of the answers do not deal with vino. So I guess it is not a dupe.

Answer (score 3):

Must have SSH enabled and root access to the server, then, SSH to it using your normal user account and edit the /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file making the following lines in [daemon] section look as this:

```
AutomaticLoginEnable=true
AutomaticLogin=yourusername
```

Save and reboot the server by running "sudo shutdown -r now".  Once gdm restarts, it will automatically login as the specified user, and your vino-server process will then start, so you can VNC into the system again.  Don’t forget to remove those auto-login lines from /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file when you’re done.

Edited from https://encodable.com/tech/blog/2009/03/02/How_To_Access_A_VNC_Remote_Desktop_After_The_Server_Reboots

Comment: This works! Thank you!

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me after wasting so much time trying to manually start vino using `systemctl --user start vino-server.service`. I was constantly getting the error `vino-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, one should change /etc/gdm3/custom.conf to allow for (auto-login + vino-server), and once in the session revert the changes for security reasons. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

create a systemd unit or service to run vino server at startup

1. ```
   cd /etc/systemd/system/
   ```
2. ```
   sudo vim vinostartup.service
   ```
3. ```
   [Unit]
   Description = description about the service
   After = network.target
   [Service]
   ExecStart = /usr/lib/vino/vino-server
   [Install]
   WantedBy = multi-user.target
   ```
4. Enable the service

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable vinostartup.service
   ```
5. Verify it using below command vinostartup.service will be there

   ```
   ls multi-user.target.wants/
   ```
6. If you don’t want to wait until next boot (it’s already enabled) we can start the service

   ```
   sudo systemctl start vinostartup.service
   ```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work, unfortunately :(

Comment: Thanks it did not work

Comment: This process does NOT work, atleast in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score -1):

`vino-server` could not start with `systemd` successfully,it will look for a mir server and return a socket error on my ubuntu desktop.It looks like the gnome developers have recently added a systemd compile option to the project
The correct way to do this is to use the **Startup Application** in you desktop distro
Find the autostart program of yout distro from here [archlinux autostarting page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autostarting#On_desktop_environment_startup) base on your own desktop enviroment

[Here is the full instructions of configuring vino server](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vino#Running_on_a_headless_server)

For example: I use an xfce desktop
 Navigate to : Start->Applications Menu->Settings->Sessions and Startup->Application Autostart and find the 'Desktop Sharing' and enable it or you can just add  `/usr/lib/vino/vino-server` to it

Before that you may have to config the vino server
I have no gnome settings pannel on my xfce desktop so i run

```
$ vino-preferences
```

from the terminal to config the connecting setting

And you may have to disable the encrytion to enable vnc clients to connect to you computer

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

restart and DONE

Comment: Startup Application in a desktop won't start until you login though.  The question asks how to start the server BEFORE login.

Comment: I don't think Vino can start without user login.  The [Ubuntu VNC docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers) basically say to switch to x11vnc for that.

Comment: @endolith - It may be the case that vino-server cannot start without a session started. Check the highest voted answer... I think it also suggests doing both things (login + vino-server), even if automatically.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can go to **Control Center**, then **Startup Application** and add a new item with the command:

```
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server &
```

Comment: This doesn't happen until after you login