# Start Synergy client with SSL before login Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, synergy

The problem arises because I use SSL. The guides for no encryption work fine, such as 
[Start Synergy (or any application) BEFORE logging in Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/918137/start-synergy-or-any-application-before-logging-in-ubuntu-16-04-2-lts/921125)

I have created the file

```
    /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
```

and added the following lines

```
    [SeatDefaults]
    greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/synergyc --enable-crypto 192.168.x.x
```

In order to for the SSL encryption not to give error "failed to verify server certificate fingerprint", I have added the server's fingerprint to

```
    ~/.synergy/SSL/Fingerprints/TrustedServers.txt
```

If I run the command

```
    /usr/bin/synergyc --enable-crypto 192.168.x.x
```

after login it works fine.
If I disable SSL on the server and remove the --enable-crypto from the 50-ubuntu.conf file, it works fine.

I suspect it is because the Fingerprint of the server is in my home directory, which is not accessible to the account running the stuff before I'm logged in, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

I tried adding the fingerprint to

```
    /home/root/.synergy/SSL/Fingerprints/TrustedServers.txt
```

(none of these folders existed before), but it didn't work.

Hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fingerprint of the server needs to be added to

```
/root/.synergy/SSL/Fingerprints/TrustedServers.txt
```

As the home directory of the root user is not `/home/root/` but `/root`, as per this question [What is "~" (home directory) defined as for programs running before login using LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958993/what-is-home-directory-defined-as-for-programs-running-before-login-using?noredirect=1&lq=1)