# What is "~" (home directory) defined as for programs running before login using LightDM?

Tags: 16.04, lightdm, home-directory, ssl, synergy

I execute a command on boot, before logging in, by adding it to my

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
```

file under `[SeatDefaults]`.

The program executes but is unable to locate a necessary file in my home directory, which makes sense as it doesn't know which home directory to look in.

So, where can I put the file so the script is able to locate it? What is the value of `~` when the program is running?

This is a reformulation of [Start Synergy client with SSL before login Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/957780/start-synergy-client-with-ssl-before-login-ubuntu-16-04-lts), in the hope of this question being easier to answer.

Comment: I guess It should be `/root` .

Comment: Oh, just `/root` instead of `/home/root`?

Comment: Depends on the user running the shell and the environment. Some shells , chron for example, it is unset. Because it is ambiguous I highly advise you use the full path in scripts. If you call it more than once, set a variable.

Comment: @Atnas, root's home directory is /root, not /home/root because historically it was typical to have /home on a separate disk and/or filesystem so if you needed to boot into rescue mode with no other filesystems mounted, root's home directory needed to be in the root filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier just to manually specify the **absolute path** (using no *relative* symbols like `~`) for the script.

Instead of declaring the location as `~/path/to/program.sh`, make it `/home/username/path/to/program/sh`.

---

Edit: If you don't have the ability to change the defined path, the `~` location is `/root` by default. You can move your script to this path with

```
sudo mv ~/path/to/program.sh /root/
```

Comment: I'm not defining the path myself, but running a piece of software that looks for it's settings in the home directory, so this won't work. Can I edit my question to make this clearer?

Comment: Ah okay then it is most likely `/root` (not `/home/root` -- the default is different for the `root` account) -- as you can see for yourself by running `echo $HOME` as `root`

Comment: @Atnas Sure you can [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/958993/edit), please do so!

Comment: I will test this on my machine tomorrow, and accept the answer if it works.