# (Lubuntu 18.10+LXQt) Start Program at Login Screen

Tags: lubuntu, synergy, lxqt

I'm trying to get Synergy to start at the login screen so I don't have to keep using a separate keyboard and mouse to log in whenever I have to reboot.

This answer seems to be good for the `*ubuntus` that use `lightdm`: https://askubuntu.com/a/920357

So for Lubuntu with LXQt, where do I put:

`/usr/bin/synergyc 192.168.x.x`

Comment: I guess you'll need to search for synergy + sddm which is what Lubuntu 18.10 uses. I found https://github.com/bgdawes/personal-config-files/wiki/Synergy

Comment: You could also try out any of the support links listed here: https://lubuntu.me/links/ including IRC.