# Cannot browse network while in VNC

Tags: networking, nautilus, vnc

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I installed desktop with minimum recommended software. I've also installed VNCServer which works fine. When I physically log on I can use the "Browse Network" in nautilus. But when I go in through VNC using the same user I get this error message.

What am I missing that needs to be turned on?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** How are you connecting? LAN? VPN? From another Ubuntu machine? Windows?

Comment: It's my home network, so LAN. I'm using VNC viewer on Win10 to remote into Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this same issue. Adding the following line to my xstartup file before "gnome-session &" seemed to fix it for me:

```
eval `dbus-launch --sh-syntax --exit-with-session`
gnome-session &
```