# Can't get Vnc to work reliably over wifi under lubuntu

Tags: ssh, vnc

I have a fresh new Lenovo G50-30 on which I installed fresh Lubuntu 15.10. It is connected over wifi to a ab/g (not n) wireless router with fixed channel. I would like to be able to reliably vnc into this computer.

At first it was dropping wifi about every few minutes or so. I think I corrected this problem by disabling ipv6 (edit wifi connection, ipv6 Settings ->Method Ignore). I also have installed some auto wifi reconnect scripts which are working. When I do all my tests I'm sure the internet connection is working without problem because I'm skyping simultaneously without interruption or image freeze.

I have setted up remote desktop by following 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/RemoteDesktop

And sometimes (5% of the time) I can connect remotely just fine using either vinagre or xvncviewer. But most of the time, it doesn't even ask for the vnc password. And sometimes it does, but doesn't proceed further, whether I try to connect over a ssh tunnel or directly through the router forwarded to vnc port.

I can remotely ssh to my computer 100% of the time. Then I've tried to restart vino by following :
1. ssh to that machine and authenticate as x
2. sudo -s to become root
3. export DISPLAY=:0.0
4. xhost +
5. exit from root shell using exit
6. export DISPLAY=:0.0
7. start vino-server using /usr/lib/vino/vino-server

Which restart a vino-server on port 5900. And I can see

> ** (vino-server:9177): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
>   (vino-server:9177): EggSMClient-CRITICAL **: egg_sm_client_set_mode: assertion 'global_client == NULL || global_client_mode == EGG_SM_CLIENT_MODE_DISABLED' failed
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 WARNING: Width (1366) is not a multiple of 4. VncViewer has problems with that.
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Autoprobing TCP port in (all) network interface
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Listening IPv6://[::]:5900
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Listening IPv4://0.0.0.0:5900
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Autoprobing selected port 5900
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Re-binding socket to listen for VNC connections on TCP port 5900 in (all) interface
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Listening IPv6://[::]:5900
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Listening IPv4://0.0.0.0:5900
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Clearing securityTypes
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Clearing securityTypes
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Advertising authentication type: 'No Authentication' (1)
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Re-binding socket to listen for VNC connections on TCP port 5900 in (all) interface
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Listening IPv6://[::]:5900
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Listening IPv4://0.0.0.0:5900
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Clearing securityTypes
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Clearing authTypes
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Advertising authentication type: 'VNC Authentication' (2)
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Clearing securityTypes
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Clearing authTypes
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Advertising security type: 'TLS' (18)
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Advertising authentication type: 'VNC Authentication' (2)
>   02/11/2015 13:26:12 Advertising security type: 'VNC Authentication' (2)

There seems to be a CRITICAL error which I tried to correct without success by uninstalling and reinstalling vino 
[Vino-server does not work since update to 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77356/vino-server-does-not-work-since-update-to-11-10)
but this would be a rather old bug for it to still be uncorrected.

I have done various reboots of both router and computers.

I have already physically travelled 3 times to the physical location to correct the connectivity problems, and would like to avoid any more trips.

How can I vnc reliably into my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question : I stopped using vino-server (which is buggy I think) and used x11vnc :
http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/x11vnc and it now works fine.